# Unable to solve Error inflating class for NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigationview

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The app crashes while compilation, **the crash report are** :

> java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

I was strucked, Please provide idea to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: add the code of class.

Comment: please check the code @W4R10CK

Answer (score 0):

You must add support libraries to your project.

1. v7 Support
2. v4 Suport
3. V13 Support
4. Design support library

Edit  - 
I have used following code snippet and it worked for me. 
i.e.

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer_sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer_sample"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_sample_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And if it does not work out please create a new NavigationDrawer Activity. By following steps

Right Click on Activity Package > New > Activity> NavigationDrawer Activity. It will generate a proper code. And you can then work upon.

Comment: added those four libraries but still getting same error

Comment: Share XML file associated with the Activity having navigation View.

Comment: i gone through the stackoverflow completely but unable to fix the problem. I think some thing iam missing, Could you please help me to move forward

Comment: I have given my used xml snipped otherwise create a new Navigation Drawer Activity as i have mentioned in the edited answer.